# Interactive learning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

I'm new in NLP and text mining and I'm trying to build a documents classifier.
Once the model is trained, we test it on new documents (they, test-data, don't have labels). It is expected that the model is not 100% accurate; so for misclassified documents, we want interact with a user to correct these bad predictions.

I've two ideas:

- Retrain the model where: traindata = old_traindata + data corrected by the user.
- After each user's rectification, update model parameters.

Does this sound correct? in the second case, which kind of algorithms should I use? How efficiently can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this but it will be a very intensive task if you plan on retraining the model on the whole data again and again if it is on a daily basis. Instead of retraining the model completely, you should try transfer learning. Save your model and then load it back and train it on the data corrected by the user. The model will be able to correct it mistakes without losing what it has already learned. The problem with transfer learning is that after some time, it will get fine tuned to the new data that you will have to retrain it from scratch. But this is far better then retraining the model every day.

You should have proper metrics in place to check if your models accuracy starts dropping in the old data after several iterations of "transfer learning". If the accuracy drops, just retrain the model on all of the data till date and you will be good to go.